# How to create an application log and save it?

Tags: java, android, logging, error-handling

I have an Android application and I want to save the error logs in a file so I can solve this errors and bugs and know what is happening with the users while they are using the app. How can I make this?

Answer (score 0):

This guide will help you through most of it; https://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and

The main focus point is the rebinding of System.out and System.err to output streams that goto file. with;

```
System.setOut()
```

and

```
System.setErr()
```

Answer (score 0):

One: Try to solve all your bugs beforehand. Granted can only catch 99%.

Two: You could get them to install Log Collector (free, lightweight) and ask them, when they contact you with problems, to repeat error and send on detailed logs from time of problem. The phones log so much, you could be inundated otherwise?